# R - Exporting a List through Openxlsx with Separately Sorted Columns Placing NA Values Last

Tags: r, openxlsx

**Solution found**! Scroll to the end to see what I did. Hopefully, this function can help others.

---

TLDR: I have a list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t6Ej.png

and I need to do something like this to it

```
lapply(irabdf, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
```

But I need this function to do this to each element of the list individually, and not delete the column names. Currently, I can get it to sort lowest to highest but it moves everything into a single column and deletes the column names.

---

I have a list in R that I am exporting as a XLS file using the Openxlsx package. I have everything that I need functionally, but my P.I has requested that I sort each column lowest to highest for reviewers, as there are a lot of empty cells that make the document look funny. I am trying to add this feature in R so that I don't need to do it manually. All columns were created from separate .csv files, and rows are unimportant.

**The List:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t6Ej.png

**The generated XLSX file looks like this:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftg00.png.

The columns are not blank, the data is just much further down.

My code for writing the file:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
lapply(names(master), function(i){
  addWorksheet(wb=wb, sheetName = names(master[i]))
  writeData(wb, sheet = i, master[[i]])
  addFilter(wb, sheet = i, rows = 1, cols = 1:(a))
  })
#Save Workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, saveFile, overwrite = TRUE)
```

a = this value obtained through (length(unique(x)). X is the levels of a variable.

**What I have:**

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
1. 1        NA       NA       NA
2. 2        NA       NA       NA
3. NA       3        NA       NA
4. NA       4        NA       NA
5. NA       NA       5        NA
6. NA       NA       6        NA
7. NA       NA       NA       7
8. NA       NA       NA       8
```

**What I want:**

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
1. 1        3        5        7
2. 2        4        6        8
3. NA       NA       NA       NA
4. NA       NA       NA       NA
5. NA       NA       NA       NA
6. NA       NA       NA       NA
7. NA       NA       NA       NA
8. NA       NA       NA       NA
```

The actual file has 1,000's of rows and 100's of blank cells for each column. The solution would replicate this across all tabs of the XLSX file.

**What I have tried:**
In a previous version of this script I was able to do this. I had separate df's which were assigned names through user-dialogue options. This is an example of the code I used to do that.

```
irabdf <- masterdf %>%
    filter(Fluorescence == "Infrared") %>%
    select(mean, Conditions) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%    
    spread(Conditions, mean) %>%
    select(!row)

irabdf <- lapply(irabdf, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])) %>%  ## Move NAs to the bottom of the df
         data.frame()

# Create a blank workbook
WB <- createWorkbook()

# Add some sheets to the workbook
addWorksheet(WB, gab)
addWorksheet(WB, rab)
addWorksheet(WB, irab)

# Write the data to the sheets
writeData(WB, sheet = gab, x = gabdf)
writeData(WB, sheet = rab, x = rabdf)
writeData(WB, sheet = irab, x = irabdf)

# Reorder worksheets
worksheetOrder(WB) <- c(1:3)

# Export the file
saveWorkbook(WB, saveFile)
```

Now that I have removed the user interface and am now using a list I can no longer do this. I have also tried a myriad of other things with most utilizing lapply.

If you need any more information just ask.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

---

***09/21***

I think I am getting closer but I still haven't resolved the issue.

When I use this code

```
list <- lapply(master[[1]],
     function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
```

I get the results I want but end up losing the first element. If I could keep the first element and apply this over my entire list that should do the trick.

---

***09/22***

I have found something that works! However, it isn't dynamic. If someone could help me loop this function across all of the elements of this list (or knows a better solution) just let me know.

```
list1 <- lapply(master[[1]],
     function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))

list1 <- data.frame(list1)

master[[1]] <- list1
```

I need to specify list1 as a df for me to maintain my column names in my XLSX output.

---

***09/22 - 2***

Okay, I have the script doing exactly what I want it to do. However, it isn't pretty and it isn't "very" dynamic.

+rep to anyone who can help me convert this into a pretty lapply loop!

```
    if (b >= 1) {
    list1 <- lapply(master[[1]],
    function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
    list1 <- data.frame(list1)
    master[[1]] <- list1
}
if (b >= 2) {   
    list2 <- lapply(master[[2]],
    function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
    list2 <- data.frame(list2)
    master[[2]] <- list2
}
```

ect... x12

b has a value of 12 here. However, it could be any number practically.

---

***09/22 - 3***

Alright, I figured it out. I created the following loop to do what I needed to do and everything appears to be working perfectly. Part of me wants to scream from happiness.

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(masterdf$ABwant))) {
  if (i >= 1)
  list.i <- lapply(master[[i]],
    function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
    list.i<- data.frame(list.i)
    master[[i]] <- list.i
}
```

I'll keep the thread open the rest of the week and if someone has a better solution I will accept it and give you some rep. Else, GG.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no found the solution to this problem yet. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: do you have data you could share that would replicate the issue? I doubt it's the issue, but what is length of x?  If you just want to add filters to the top of the rows you could use writeDataTable instead of writeData and addfilter commands. the writeDataTable automatically adds a filter to the first row and you wouldn't need to specify number of columns

Comment: Hey Jonni, thank you for the reply.

X is the number of unique levels of a variable. And the filter command is just something I added to make my life easier in the interim. Once I get things properly sorted I will remove it. Currently, this works as intended.

If my issue isn't clear, I will happily go into more detail. Just let me know! Ultimately, I just don't want empty spaces in my generated XLSX file.

Comment: Will you elaborate on what I need to share? Are you wanting to see more of the list I am generating?

Comment: I'm getting close but haven't gotten the solution just yet. I have updated my post.

Comment: I have figured out a way to get the results that I want but it isn't dynamic. If anyone could help me loop my solution (under 09/22 in the OP) across all elements in a list then I think things would be perfect.

Comment: I figured it out! I have a dynamic solution. If anyone else would like to add something I will give you rep.

Comment: Hey Robert, congrats on solving it. Just saw your comment from earlier. It is helpful if you provide a reproducible example that others can use to help. It is more challenging to just look at the code and pictures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: For sure, going forward I will make sure to add a reproducible example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the code that I used to create the loop that I wanted.

```
 for (i in 1:length(unique(masterdf$ABwant))) {
  if (i >= 1)
  list.i <- lapply(master[[i]],
    function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
    list.i<- data.frame(list.i)
    master[[i]] <- list.i
}
```

Using OpenXLSX, I was able to use this loop to create an Excel file that has a separate tab for each antibody and has all columns sorted with NA values placed at the bottom.

```
### Creating the Excel file
wb <- createWorkbook()
lapply(names(master), function(i){
  addWorksheet(wb=wb, sheetName = names(master[i]))
  writeData(wb, sheet = i, master[[i]])
     # Saving the Excel file
saveWorkbook(wb, saveFile, overwrite = TRUE)
```